# Mongo query with regex fails when backslash\newline are present

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm using MongoDB with Sails.

```
db.post.find( { body:  {"$regex" : /^.*twitter.*$/i }}).
```

This query is supposed to find only posts which contain 'twitter' in their body-field.
For some reason it won't find a match if a backslash is present in the field (like a newline).

Is this known? What can I do about it?

Here are two examples to showcase the problem:

This document **is** returned by the find-command above:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e0d7eac2280519ac14cfda"), 
    "title" : "Cool Post", 
    "body" : "Twitter Twitter twitter twittor"
}
```

This document **is not** returned by the find-command above:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e0d7eac2280519ac14cfdb"), 
    "title" : "Cool Post with Linebreaks", 
    "body" : "This is a cool post with Twitter mentioned into it \n Foo bar"
}
```

Comment: I just added two documents, one which is found currently and one which won't be found (because it contains \n

Comment: If you just want to find anywhere in the string, instead of adding begin and end of line matches (`^.*` and `.*$`) you can simplify your regex to: `db.post.find( { body:  {"$regex" : /twitter/i }})`. Note that a case-insensitive regex query isn't going to be overly efficient; best case will be a full index scan if there is a suitable one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this known?*

No. Its not an issue with the `MongoDb` search Engine.

> *What can I do about it?*

You could change your `Regular Expression` to:

```
var regex = new RegExp("twitter","i");
db.posts.find( { body:  regex});
```

The problem with your code is the decimal point `.`

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions),

> `.`
>
> (The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline
>   character.

which is why the string with a `newline` character is not taken to be a match.

Comment: Since I'm using the framework Sails.js I added the 'm' modifier to their query and submitted a pull request. Let's see whether they like it. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @Hedge, I have updated my answer, to indicate why your query Regular Expression doesn't work.